# How to load all dependencies in Main.js using Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

So I have setup my Aurelia application in the following way and I want to import all my modules and dependencies in Main.js and still be able to inject dependencies in modules like Start.js. I also want to display a splash screen that waits until everything is loaded. Is any of this possible?

main.js

```
    import 'bootstrap';
    // TODO: Import all modules here
    // import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
    // import {PortalData} from "./portalData";

    object export function configure(aurelia){        

            aurelia.use
                .standardConfiguration()
                .developmentLogging();

            // start aurelia and navigate to app.html / app.js
            aurelia.start().then(a=> a.setRoot());        
        }
```

app.js

```
export class App {

    // aurelia convention
    configureRouter(config, router)
    {
        this.router = router;

        config.map([                
            {
                route:["", "home"], 
                moduleId:"./start", 
                title:"SevaLink", 
                nav:true
            }
```

start.js

```
    import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
    import {PortalData} from "./portalData";


    @inject(PortalData)
    export class Start {

        constructor(portalData){
            this.portalData = portalData;
        }


        activate(){
            return this.portalData.getApplications()
                .then(apps => this.applications = apps);
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can import all of your dependencies in any module in your application. I'm not sure what that would accomplish, though. This would just make your application slower to start, and wouldn't really provide any benefit. Aurelia uses lazy loading for modules. If you want to load all of the code for your application at startup, just bundle the application.

Comment: I use jQuery and Velocity in selected modules not all. So I want to be able to write the import statement once in a central place instead of repeating in each module. I am already bundling everything.

Comment: That isn't how modules work. When you're using modules, you have to import each module wherever you are going to use it. If you want to have something be available globally, then you would have to attach it to the global or window object.

Comment: I think I have seen something like this in Angular 2's root module, they call it AppModule by convention. But I may have got the wrong idea there too.

Comment: Yeah, Angular 2 requires you to do all that goofiness. It isn't necessary in Aurelia.

Comment: Let's look at John Papa's Angular Tour of Heroes. Notice how the modules that are imported here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/app/app.module.ts still have to be imported where they are actually used, such as here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/app/hero-detail.component.ts Being forced to specify everything ahead of time like Angular wastes developer time and forces you to write code that the framework should be figuring out on its own. Alas, such is life for the Angular 2 developers of the world.